# unbinding function with jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, unbind

I have this function sideNav that is triggered by both clicking on a subnav item

```
$(".side-nav ul li a").click(function(event) {
    $(document).ready(sideNav());
});

if(window.location.hash) {
    $(document).ready(sideNav());
}
```

I am trying to unbind sideNav when a certain element is clicked

```
$(".side-nav .page-header h1 span").click(function(event) {

}).unbind('ready',sideNav);
```

I have tried using .live() and .die(), but these wont work on the hashtag if statement.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: All I can say is that you're doing it wrong, very wrong! Adding the parenthesis to the function executes it right away, the document ready statements are, to say the least, in the wrong place ...etc.. As for answering the question, you should be using on() and off().

Answer (score 2):

Look into jQuery [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Do to change your click(), you could do:

```
$(".side-nav ul li a").bind('click', function(event) {
    $(document).ready(sideNav());
});

$(".side-nav ul li a").unbind('click');
```

Comment: This would be the answer except it doesn't work on the if statement.

Comment: @user1521516 I don't have much experience with hashes in JS, but it would appear than your if statement is either false at the time of execution or is a contingency. This isn't the fault of jQuery, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) would be the preferred way to attach and detach event handlers.

Also, wrap the code in document ready to make sure the DOM has loaded when you execute the code, do not wrap every function in it's own document ready function.

When you referrence a function, you type just the function name "`sideNav`", if you add the parenthesis, like "`sideNav()`" you execute that function right away and pass back the value of that function, and the default value unless something else is returned is "undefined", and when adding the parenthesis your document ready functions aren't working at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".side-nav ul li a").on('click', sideNav);

    $(".side-nav .page-header h1 span").on('click', function() {
        $(".side-nav ul li a").off('click');
    });
});
```